# Systemjs-builder, basic useage / configuration

Tags: builder, systemjs

Hello I'm trying to test the systemjs-builder, the readme has a nice getting started section but where do I put the builder code?

https://github.com/systemjs/builder

The code I'm referring to is below, I'm not sure where to put this (is this the builder.config?):

```
var path = require("path");
var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');

// optional constructor options
// sets the baseURL and loads the configuration file
var builder = new Builder('path/to/baseURL', 'path/to/system/config-file.js');

builder
.bundle('local/module.js', 'outfile.js')
.then(function() {
 console.log('Build complete');
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Build error');
  console.log(err);
});
```

Is there a demo build out there that I can look at?

Comment: You can put it in the standalone builder script, for example in a file named build.js, and try running it with node, like `node build.js`. Then you can add it to npm scripts in your package.json, or add it to your build process if you are using gulp or something alike.

Comment: Here's an example using gulp https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1115444/Developing-And-Deploying-An-Angular-Application-Wi

Answer (score 0):

You'd put that in your front-end building pipeline. For instance, inside of a gulp task.

While in a development build you could just serve all your files separately, in a production build you'd bundle and minify them to reduce the number of HTTP requests.